# Twitter typeahead.js templates settings being ignored

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I have a search box in the navbar that is using Twitter typeahead.js v0.11.1 to call WebApi and return results based on the input of the search box, which works fine.

However, when I try to add templates settings, they are ignored and the single name jsonProperty continues to be the only thing returned in the dropdown.

I have set up typeahead as follows

```
var matchList = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('SmartSearchDto'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url:  'http://myserver/api/smartsearch/search?searchTerm=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
matchList.initialize();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    templates: {
            suggestion: function(data) { 
            return '<p><strong>' + data.name + '</strong> - ' +  data.entitytype + '</p>';
            }
        }
    },
    {
        displayKey: 'name',
        name: 'SmartSearchDto',
        source: matchList.ttAdapter()
    }
);
```

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 minute after posting I worked it out:

```
 var matchList = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('SmartSearchDto'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url:  'http://localhost:59019/api/smartsearch/search?searchTerm=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
matchList.initialize();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
    },
    {
        templates: {
            suggestion: function(data) { 
              return '<p><strong>' + data.name + '</strong> - ' + data.entitytype + '</p>';
            }
        },
        source: matchList.ttAdapter()
    }
);
```

Comment: What was the resolution? Also having issues here.

Comment: Changing the code from what I had in the original question to what I have pasted into the above answer